# EmberCli:: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, ember-cli

I have a Ruby on Rails application which has an ember app within itself. I have installed all the related packages perfectly. I am running the Rails application through Apache - Phusion Passenger. But when I go to browser and load the application I get `EmberCli::App::BuildError`.

Here is the application trace (Error)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
  at Object.TransFormDotComponentInvocation._isMulipartPath (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:14387:24)
  at Object.TransFormDotComponentInvocation._isInlineInvocation (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:14391:16)
  at traverse.MustacheStatement (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:14416:21)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2753:36)
  at visitKey (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2791:27)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2767:17)
  at visitArray (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2805:26)
  at visitKey (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2789:13)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2767:17)
  at visitArray (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2805:26)
  at visitKey (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2789:13)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2767:17)
  at visitArray (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2805:26)
  at visitKey (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2789:13)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2767:17)
  at visitKey (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2791:27)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2767:17)
  at visitArray (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2805:26)
  at visitKey (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2789:13)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2767:17)
  at visitArray (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2805:26)
  at visitKey (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2789:13)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2767:17)
  at visitArray (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2805:26)
  at visitKey (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2789:13)
  at visitNode (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2767:17)
  at traverse (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:2841:9)
  at Object.TransFormDotComponentInvocation.transform (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:14414:7)
  at Object.preprocess (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:3463:35)
  at precompile (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:1290:34)
  at Object.precompile (<ember-app-folder>/bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js:15389:12)
  at Object.module.exports.template (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/utils.js:29:40)
  at TemplateCompiler.processString (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/ember-cli-htmlbars/index.js:68:36)
  at Promise.then.result.output (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/lib/strategies/persistent.js:41:23)
  at initializePromise (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:589:5)
  at new Promise$1 (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1077:33)
  at <ember-app-folder>/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/lib/strategies/persistent.js:40:18
  at tryCatch (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:539:12)
  at invokeCallback (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:554:13)
  at publish (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:522:7)
  at flush (<ember-app-folder>/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2414:5)
  at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
```

Below are my node, ember version and OS.

```
ember-cli: 2.7.0
node: 5.5.0
Ruby: 2.3.1
Rails: 4.2.1
npm: 2.14.10
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
```

I am attaching my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ember-app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for ember app goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "active-model-adapter": "2.0.3",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.2.0",
    "ember-cli": "1.13.13",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.5",
    "ember-cli-coffeescript": "1.13.2",
    "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-emblem": "0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.4",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-cli-rails-addon": "0.0.13",
    "ember-cli-release": "0.2.8",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "1.13.15",
    "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.4",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.0.7",
    "emberx-select": "2.0.2",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.3"
  }
}
```

I am attaching my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "account-settings",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "^2.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.0.6",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.1",
    "ember-data": "^2.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "0.1.7",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.16",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.20",
    "jquery": "1.11.3",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.4.0",
    "qunit": "~1.20.0"
  }
}
```

Where is my problem?